# Elasticsearch 2.3 - delete documents by query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 2.3 & Sense and trying to delete documents by query.

I refer to these docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/delete-by-query-usage.html

**Request**

```
DELETE /monitors/monitor/_query
{
  "term": { "ProcessName" : "myProcName" }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "found": false,
  "_index": "monitors",
  "_type": "monitor",
  "_id": "_query",
  "_version": 11,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

As you can see, i'm not getting any results even though I have ProcessName named "myProcName".
Response also tells that the engine looks for `_id` equals to `_query`.

**EDIT 1:**
Even when sending request:

```
DELETE /monitors/monitor/_query
{
  "query": {
    "term": { "ProcessName" : "tibapp_qflowfile" }
  }
}
```

I'm getting response:

```
{
  "found": false,
  "_index": "monitors",
  "_type": "monitor",
  "_id": "_query",
  "_version": 1,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Your query needs to be wrapped within a `"query": {}`, i.e. `{"query":{"term": { "ProcessName" : "myProcName" }}}`

Comment: @Val Hi man.. I've edited my question

Comment: What do you get when running `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v'` ?

Comment: @Val I get: "name component version type url"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you're getting means that you haven't installed the delete-by-query plugin, which isn't installed by default.

[Do that first](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugins-delete-by-query.html), restart your node and it will work afterwards

```
bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```

Comment: I've tried to downloaded as a file, and install it via command line.
I'm getting an error, even though the file is NOT corrupted:

-> Installing from file:/C:/delete-by-query-2.3.1.zip...
Trying file:/C:/delete-by-query-2.3.1.zip ...
Downloading .DONE
Verifying file:/C:/delete-by-query-2.3.1.zip
 checksums if available ...
NOTE: Unable to verify checksum for downloaded plugin (unable to find .sha1 or .
md5 file to verify)
ERROR: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 30926 bytes)

Comment: Weird, are you sure you can open that ZIP you downloaded?

Comment: Sure, I even extracted the files:
delete-by-query-2.3.1.jar
plugin-descriptor.properties

Answer (score 1):

FYI - The Plugin [delete-by-query] is incompatible with Elasticsearch [2.3.5]. Was designed for version [2.3.4]