# Deleting data in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to delete data in ElasticSearch that matches query. Im using ElasticSeach 1.5 and Im doing this query to achieve this:

```
POST employee/report/_delete_by_query
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
           [                 
                   { "match_phrase" : { "year_month" : "2016-8" }  },
                   { "term" : { "status" : "Inactive" }  }
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And when I do this, I get this result:

```
{
   "_index": "employee",
   "_type": "report",
   "_id": "_delete_by_query",
   "_version": 6,
   "created": false
}
```

Every time I run the query, the _version numbers gets +1.
Then I query the terms deleted, to check that there're no more results:

```
GET employee/report/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
           [                 
                   { "match_phrase" : { "year_month" : "2016-8" }  },
                   { "term" : { "status" : "Inactive" }  }
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And Im still getting results! What Im doing wrong? Do I need to refresh ElasticSearch? Im missing some step?

Comment: This answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563687/elasticsearch-2-3-delete-documents-by-query/36564375#36564375

Comment: Im working with version 1.5.2 so I think it's already a core function, then they removed it, and then they wrote another api to this... Im wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of using the delete-by-query API is as follows, i.e. you need to hit the `_query` endpoint using the `DELETE` HTTP method:

```
DELETE employee/report/_query
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
           [                 
                   { "match_phrase" : { "year_month" : "2016-8" }  },
                   { "term" : { "status" : "Inactive" }  }
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}
```